# The impossible $\arcsin(2)$ pops up in an integral

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Use $$\int _0^af\left(x\right)dx=ab-\int _0^bf^{-1}\left(x\right)dx$$
> to evaluate $$\int _0^2\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\:dx$$, given that $f(x)$ is increasing, $a>0$ and $f(a)=b$

I think it is natural to let $f^{-1}(x) = \arcsin{x/4}$. Then $b = 2 = f(a) = \sin(a/4)$

Then $a = 4\arcsin{2}$. What went wrong?

Comment: $\int _0^af\left(x\right)dx=ab-\int _0^bf^{-1}\left(x\right)dx$
 May you please clarify upon this result/formula? I have never seen this.

Comment: @RiverX15 The idea is that $\int_0^a f(x)dx + \int_0^b f^{-1}(x)dx = ab$.  This is based on the presumption that $f$ is either strictly  increasing, or strictly decreasing.  Either way, the 1st integral equals the area under the curve, as $x$ goes from $x=0$ to $x=a$.  The 2nd integral equals the area to the *left* of the **same curve**, as $y$ goes from $y = 0$ to $y = b$.  Then, you reason that together, the two areas fit together to form the rectangular area bounded by the two axes, $x = a$ and $y = b$.

Comment: You have $f(a) = 4 \sin a$, not $f(a) = \sin(a/4)$

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you very much for the clarification!

Answer (score 5):

Your error comes from the computation of the inverse. If $y=f^{-1}(x)=\arcsin\frac{x}{4}$, then you have $\sin y=\frac{x}{4}$ and $x=4\,\sin y$, so the inverse is $f(x)=4\,\sin x$ and $a=\arcsin\frac12$.

NOTE: Your [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) is only valid if $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The equation
$$
\int _0^a f(x)\,\mathrm dx = a{f(a)} - \int _0^{f(a)} f^{-1}(x)\,\mathrm dx \tag1
$$
is presented in this format as a helpful aid to solving integrals,
with the intention that you will match your given integral to the
**left** side of the equation and then work out what the right side will be.
(Note I have made the substitution $b = f(a)$ in order to reduce the number of symbols I have to deal with a few paragraphs later in this answer.)

I would say the **natural** way to use the formula is the way it was intended to be used.

Of course you **can** use the formula by matching your integral on the right side and solving, if you really want. In fact, by simple algebraic rules (subtracting or adding equal quantities on both sides), Equation $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$
\int _0^{f(a)} f^{-1}(x)\,\mathrm dx = a{f(a)} - \int _0^a f(x)\,\mathrm dx. \tag2
$$
If you plug your integral into the right-hand side of Equation $(1)$ and then solve for your integral, the right-hand side of Equation $(2)$ is the solution you will get. Notice that Equation $(2)$ is related to Equation $(1)$ in another way:
if you rename the function $f^{-1}$ to $f$ and then rename $f^{-1}(a)$ to $a$, you have Equation $(1)$ all over again.
It's not really a different technique, it just opens more possibilities for
awkwardness and confusion and therefore for error.

But whichever way you do it, it won't work unless you can correctly invert
the function whose rule is $x \mapsto \arcsin(x/4),$
whatever name you give that function.
The correct inverse has already been explained several times.

Comment: I always tell my students to try to guess what the teacher intended. You are right to point out the importance of pragmatic thinking.

Answer (score 2):

You have $f(x)=\arcsin(\frac x4)$  It is not true that $f^{-1}(x)=\arcsin(\frac x4)$.  You need to invert $y=\arcsin(\frac x4)$ to get $f^{-1}(x)$

Comment: Ok. But why is it incorrect to let $f^{-1}(x)=\arcsin(\frac x4)$ as I did?

Comment: Because it conflicts with your definition of $f(x)$, which is required for the theorem you are supposed to use.  The theorem draws $f(x)$ from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$.  The left side integrates below the curve.  The right side takes the rectangle and subtracts the area to the left of the curve.

Answer (score 1):

If you call $f^{-1}(x)=\arcsin(x/4)$, then $f(x)=4\sin(x)$. And since you are integrating between $0$ and $2$, then $b=2=f(a)=4\sin(a)$, that is $a=\pi/6$.